# Customize Spring Data REST to expose only selected methods from Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Spring Data Rest exposes all finder methods in Repository layer and also Schema for Entity after RestRepository annotation is applied to Repository and RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration is enabled.

How can we expose selected methods in repository only and disable entity schema exposure as REST

Also if some Entity property has to be not shown in Json, do we need to anotate JsonIgnore in Entity itself ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im afraid you will have to use 
@RestResource(exported=false) either on each method ( so overriding it ).

2nd question: yes, use JsonIgnore.

Comment: also, can we change method from GET to POST for some find method since at one place I am finding by email and password and that is best sent from POST ?

Comment: You are trying to GET info from serwer.. not updating anything so GET is right choice here

Comment: in my case, those 2 fields are email and password. I think i should set RestExpose to false for only this findByEmailAndPassword method and handle it using conventional style